# Java conversion of base 16 to base 64

Tags: java, cryptography, integer, base64, number-systems

I wrote a solution in Java to solve the problem [here](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1/). I use `BigInteger` to convert first from base 16 to base 10, then base 10 to base 64.

This seems quite inefficient to me, and I would have no idea how to do this if I couldn't use `BigInteger`.  I'm sure there's a nice and clever way to do this using a lot more bit manipulation.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class Base64{

    //according to RFC 4648 and RFC 2045
    public final static char[] base64alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();
    public final static char base64pad = '='; //unused

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String test = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
        System.out.println( base16to64( test ) );
    }

    /**Return the base 64 value of an input base 16 string.
     */
    public static String base16to64(String hex){
        BigInteger value = base16to10(hex); //base 10 value

        // --- convert base 10 to 64 ---
        int digits = 1; // # digits in base 64 we'll need
        while( value.compareTo(new BigInteger("64").pow(digits)) != -1 ){ //while the decimal value >= 64^i
            digits++;
        }

        String ret = "";
        for(int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--){ //start at most significant digit

            //this digit must be an A (represents 0)
            if( value.subtract(new BigInteger("64").pow(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == -1){
                ret += "A";
            }
            else{
                for(int d = 63; d >= 1; d--){
                    //digit found: [ value - (64^i)*d >= 0 ]  with d the greatest possible
                    if( value.subtract(new BigInteger("64").pow(i).multiply(
                            new BigInteger(Integer.toString(d)))).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != -1){
                        value = value.subtract(new BigInteger("64").pow(i).multiply( new BigInteger(Integer.toString(d))));
                        ret += base64alphabet[d];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }//end else
        }

        return ret;
    }//end base16to64()

    /**Return the BigInteger decimal value of an input hexadecimal string.
     */
    public static BigInteger base16to10(String hex){
        hex = hex.toLowerCase();

        //hex is 0-9 then a-f
        BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO; //base 10 value
        for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){ //moving from most significant digit towards 16^0

            int digit = (int) hex.charAt(i);
            //if the hex digit is 0-9
            if( '0' <= hex.charAt(i) && hex.charAt(i) <= '9')
                digit = digit - '0'; 
            //else the hex digit is a-f
            else
                digit = digit - 'a' + 10; 

            BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("" + digit); // digit as BigInt
            temp = temp.multiply( new BigInteger("16").pow( hex.length() - 1 - i) ); // digit * 16^index
            value = value.add(temp);
        }

        return value;
    }//end base16to10()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working too hard. Java has a [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class that does most of the work for you, all you need to do is combine it and [the constructor for BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-), and you are done.

```
public static String base16to64(String hex){
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray());
}
```

For the linked example input:

> 49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d

We get the correct output:

> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

---

If you wanted to implement the base 64 conversion yourself, note that you are still doing too much work. Your `base16to10` function could be replaced with

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```

One function completely cut out.

---

However, if you don't want to use `BigInteger` at all (this is generally a bad idea, but for programming practice, you might want to), notice that `log(64)/log(16) == 1.5`. Thus, for every 1.5 hex digits, we can obtain 1 base 64 digits.

So take the last `2` hex digits of the hex string: `6d`. In binary, this is `01101101`. We only need to consider `101101`, which is `45`. So we take the 45th element of the base 64 alphabet: `t`. That's the last digit of the base 64 string. Now just shift the hex string over by 6 bits, and repeat (note, shifting by 6 bits won't be clean, so it's probably easier to instead process 3 hex digits to 2 base 64 digits, and take off the last two elements of the hex string).

But noticing the "Cryptopals Rule":

> Always operate on raw bytes, never on encoded strings. Only use hex and base64 for pretty-printing.

You should probably parse the hex string into a `byte[]` or `ArrayList<Byte>` before working on it. Honestly, I think this is way easier to do using `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a little silly.  Any suggestions on how to do this without using BigInteger/ using more bit manipulation if I were to fully implement this myself?

Answer (score 2):

Some general concerns:

> ```
> /**Return the BigInteger decimal value of an input hexadecimal string.
>  */
> ```

Usually we format Javadoc comments like so:

```
/**
 * Return the BigInteger decimal value of an input hexadecimal string.
 */
```

---

> ```
> public static BigInteger base16to10(String hex){
> ```

This function isn't actually converting base 16 to base 10. It seems like it is, but that's not really what it's doing. `BigInteger` doesn't store its data in base 10 format, so this function would be better named `parseBase16`, or something along those lines.

---

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){
>     int digit = (int) hex.charAt(i);
>     //if the hex digit is 0-9
>     if( '0' <= hex.charAt(i) && hex.charAt(i) <= '9')
>         digit = digit - '0'; 
>     //else the hex digit is a-f
>     else
>         digit = digit - 'a' + 10;
> ```

That's a lot of `hex.charAt(i)` calls. Instead, you could just do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){
    char digit = hex.charAt(i);
    int digitValue = (int) digit;

    if('0' <= digit && digit <= '9')
        digit = digitValue - '0'; 
    else
        digitValue = digitValue - 'a' + 10;
```

---

> ```
>     BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("" + digit);
>     temp = temp.multiply( new BigInteger("16").pow( hex.length() - 1 - i) ); 
>     value = value.add(temp);
> }
> ```

This is an inefficient method of constructing `BigInteger`s. Instead:

```
     BigInteger temp = BigInteger.valueOf(digit);
    temp = temp.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(16).pow( hex.length() - 1 - i)); 
    value = value.add(temp);
}
```

Although, since we always have `BigInteger.valueOf(16)`, you should really make that a `final BigInteger SIXTEEN = BigInteger.valueOf(16)` outside of the loop.

But wait. If you instead iterated over the digits in reverse, you'd start with a `BigInteger currentPowerOf16 = BigInteger.ONE`, and all you'd have to do is `currentPowerOf16 = currentPowerOf16.multiply(SIXTEEN);`, which would automatically take care of the powers for you. That would be the better way to do it; it's notably more efficient too.

---

Let's also consider your comments:

> ```
> //hex is 0-9 then a-f
> ```

You can expect your reader to know this. We all know that hexadecimal is 0-9 then a-f, so just leave this comment out.

> ```
> BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO; //base 10 value
> ```

I'm not sure what `//base 10 value` means. I'm guessing this is the result of the conversion. So I'd remove the comment and instead name this variable `result` (yes, I'm lazy on variable names).

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){ //moving from most significant digit towards 16^0
> ```

What is this? How am I "moving from the most significant digit towards 16^0"? Oh, you must mean "iterate over the digits, starting from the leftmost".

> ```
> //if the hex digit is 0-9
>   if( '0' <= hex.charAt(i) && hex.charAt(i) <= '9')
> ```

This comment is redundant with the next line of code.

> ```
> //else the hex digit is a-f
>   else
> ```

This is a good comment. However, it's best to format comments with a space:

```
// Else, the hex digit is a-f.
```

> ```
> BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("" + digit); // digit as BigInt
> ```

This is another redundant comment

> ```
> }//end base16to10()
> ```

Don't use comments to show flow of the methods. `// end if`, `// end base16to10`, etc are not useful comments. If it is necessary to include such comments to be able to figure out what is being closed with the `}`, you should refactor into yet another function. In this case, it is perfectly clear that you are ending the `base16to10` function.